# I"m having a hard time merging accounts

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I have tried to merge user: 4413928 with user: 6051639 3 times now. When I try to merge from EITHER account the only option I am presented with is to delete this account and keep the other. I have lost the password to the former and very rarely use the associated email address, so I really don't want to keep that one and delete this one.

Is there a way to keep this account (user: 6051639) and delete the other (user: 4413928)?

Comment: Can you change the email address associated with an account?  (After resetting the password).  The old email address still works, and you still have access to it, so you could do it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just merged my accounts. Don't worry about your logins, they will be merged, too. You can log in with either credentials and then go to the settings and remove the one which you don't need any longer:

[image: Logins merged]

You can't keep the account with ID 6.000.000 and get rid of the 4.000.000 one. As mentioned in the email:

> Please note that we always merge accounts into the user with the lower user ID.

But IMHO the ID does not really matter.

Comment: As mentioned in my post:

"I have lost the password to [the email account associated with the 4.000.000 account]..."

So any emails you have sent to that email address have not been read. Due to your policy of not getting rid of the 4.000.000 account in order to merge it with the 6.000.000 account, we are left with the 4.000.000 account that will never be used. I'm sure you have your reasons for such a policy. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @WesleyKitlasten: updated my answer. The logins are merged, too

Answer (score 7):

If the user interface doesn't let you merge in the way you'd like, you can try contacting the team at https://stackoverflow.com/contact

In the first dropdown that says *Please select a topic*, choose *I need to merge user profiles*. A message will appear with some additional guidance on submitting your request.